# Doob's martingale inequality. Why does $(2)$ hold true?

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, proof-explanation, expected-value, martingales

> **Doob's Martingale Inequality** Let $M=\left(M_n\right)_{n\ge0}$ be a martingale or a positive submartingale. Set $M^*_n=\sup_{j\le n}|M_j|$. Then
> $$\mathbb{P}\left(M_n^*\ge \alpha\right)\le\frac{\mathbb{E}\left\{|M_n|\right\}}{\alpha}\tag{1}$$

---

---

---

Does $(1)$ imply that for all $p\ge1$:
$$\mathbb{P}\left(M_n^*\ge \alpha\right)\le\frac{\mathbb{E}\left\{|M_n|^{\color{red}{p}}\right\}}{\alpha^{\color{red}{p}}}\tag{2}$$?

 If so, does that simply follow from the fact that:
$$\mathbb{P}\left(M_n^*\ge \alpha\right)=\mathbb{P}\left((M_n^*)^p\ge (\alpha)^p\right)\le\frac{\mathbb{E}\left\{|M_n|^\color{red}{p}\right\}}{\alpha^\color{red}{p}}\tag{3}$$?

Answer (score 0):

$\phi(x)=|x|^p$ is a positive convex function therefore $( |M_n|^p,n \ge 0)$ is also a submartingale (as long as it is in $L^p$). Hence, your implication is true.

Comment: So, $(3)$ should not suffice to explain why $(1)$ imply $(2)$?

Comment: To be honest, I found no argument in (3) to imply (1). How can you obtain the last inequality if not using Doobs?

Comment: No, what I mean is that the result "$(1)$ implies $(2)$" can be shown by means of $(3)$

Comment: I'm confused. The standard mean to obtain (3) is by Doobs inequality. This one is not Chebysevs or Markovs.